# Windows menu when left clicking on the top left corner

Tags: windows

sorry for the title but I didn't know how to express it in a few words. The idea is this. When you click with the left mouse button in the top left corner of any window program of Windows, it is opened a small menu, containing some options like: "Restore", "Minimize", "Close" etc. I tried to search google about this but I do not know even how this menu is called. What I need is the name of this menu, and also a way to customize it. I would like to add another option in that menu, if it is possible.

Comment: Right-clicking titlebar opens the same menu. How do you want to customize it? Add something to it for all programs? Or in your program?

Comment: To all programs, this is my idea, is that possible?

Comment: What do you want to add? And do you have any programming experience?

Comment: Yes, I have a good java background and somewhat even in C#. I just want to add a link to a program, for example "Open Notepad++".

Answer (score 1):

It is called the `system menu`. As far as I know, you can only add items to this menu if you write the application.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but what do you mean by "if you write the application"? I want to add an option there for all applications, not just for one.

Comment: You can also inject items from DLLs, many "minimize to tray" programs do it.

Comment: Can you help me with a tutorial about this? Or can you suggest me a page to look for?